# Diameter of set in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I do agree with the statement that

$$d(A) = \sup{\{d(x, y):x, y \in A\}}$$

But why can't we use maximum because according to me its max will also give diameter. 
I know it should not be correct, so please give me the correct explanation with example where the $\max$ formulation will be wrong.

Comment: The max doesn't always exist.

Comment: This site prefers that you use $\LaTeX$. I edited your post to show you how. You can hover your mouse over it and right-click and see the markup. At least that works on Mac, I don't know about other OS's. Or you can see the markup by editing your post. As Zachary notes, the max doesn't always exist. Can you think of an example?

Answer (score 11):

It is possible for the supremum of a set to be a value that is not in the set, and as a result the set has no maximum value (since the maximum of a set is always taken to be the largest element *in* the set).

For a simple example, consider the open interval $A = (0, 1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < x < 1\}$. What's the largest distance two elements of $A$ can be? It's not 1, because there are no elements in $A$ that are 1 apart (since 0 and 1 aren't elements of $A$). However, for any distance less than 1, you can find two elements of $A$ that are further apart than that. In fact, the set of distances is equal to $[0, 1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \le x < 1\}$.

Since 1 is not an element of that set, the maximum of the set cannot be 1. However, it also cannot be any number less than 1, since there is always a larger number than it in the set. Hence, the set has *no* maximum value. However, the set *does* have a supremum, and the value of that supremum is 1.

Comment: Thnx for answer

Comment: If you think this answer is satisfactory, you should hit the accept button.